# How to use arr.Contains with Object ArrayList

Tags: .net, object, arraylist

i have this Visual Basic .NET ArrayList

```
Dim first As New ArrayList()

            first.Add({100, 200})
            first.Add({500, 250})
            first.Add({700, 200})
```

My question is, how i can get True from this code...

```
first.Contains({500, 250})
```

Always return me False... what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Contains proves if the object you pass in is already in the ArrayList. It does not compare your values.

Sample:

```
Imports System

Public Class Sample

    Sub Method()
        Dim Obj1 As New Object()
        Dim Obj2 As New Object()
        Console.WriteLine(Obj1.Equals(Obj2)) '===> false
        Obj2 = Obj1
        Console.WriteLine(Obj1.Equals(Obj2)) '===> true
    End Sub 'Method 
End Class 'Sample
```

Here Obj1 und Obj2 are both of type Object but they are not equal even if their internal object state might be the same.

You might write your own custom class implementing IComparable to achieve want you want.

Comment: Any other fast solution? my intention is use it only to remove the not Containing values from the arraylist.